# How to convert associative array to normal array?

Tags: php

I have a device array with index

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "HPEnvy"
  1 => "iPad"
  2 => "win7protemplate"
]
```

How do I convert it to look like this ?

```
$devices = ["HPEnvy","iPad","win7protemplate"];
```

Comment: And what do you want to achieve with this? Indexes will remain the same.

Comment: It is just that is the format that my front-end developer is asking for ?

Comment: @Musa : I'm trying to produce this format exactly `["HPEnvy","iPad","win7protemplate"];`

Comment: Ok... consider your "preferred array". You do know it will produce the exact array you're trying to avoid, right? https://3v4l.org/QGcS6

Comment: Do you create some php script which in turn generate some php-code or what is the purpose for this?

Comment: @Musa in your example there are not two different array formats, but two different **output** array formats. If you want this output, you can use `json_encode`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that a frontender is asking you for this I assume he's looking for a JSON encoded array. Given your array is created like this:

```
$array = array("HPEnvy","iPad","win7protemplate");
```

Which is basically the same as (and probably causing some confusion with this question):

```
$array = ["HPEnvy","iPad","win7protemplate"];
```

Simply wrap `$array` in a [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode), like this:

```
$devices = json_encode($array);
```

This will return the **string**:

```
["HPEnvy","iPad","win7protemplate"]
```

Which can then be used in Javascript.

Comment: Good thinking. Didn't think of this from a JS perspective